# Question about uniform continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Check if

1) $f(x)=x^2$

2)$f(x)=x $

are uniform continuous on the set of reals (R)?
" Definition of Uniform continuous 
Let function f defined from R to R 
the set E is subset or equal to domain (f) 
We say f is uniform continuous on E if 
For all a (0

Comment: Do you know what uniformly continuous means? What are you having difficulty with specifically?

Comment: What do you mean by uniform continuity? Please edit the question and add what you know about the problem.

Answer (score 2):

1) consider the series $x_{n}=n^{2}+\frac{1}{n},y_{n}=n^{2}-\frac{1}{n}$, so we have $\left|x_{n}-y_{n}\right|=\frac{2}{n}\rightarrow0$, but $\left|x_{n}^{2}-y_{n}^{2}\right|=4n\rightarrow\infty$.

2) let $\epsilon>0$
 . let $\delta=\epsilon$
 . so for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$
 , if $\left|x-y\right|<\delta$
  then $\left|x-y\right|=\left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(y\right)\right|<\epsilon$
 .